# Azure Bing Image Search client throws resource not found

Tags: python, azure, bing-api

I am trying to use the bing image search SDK, but this tutorial doesn't work for me:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-image-search/quickstarts/client-libraries?pivots=programming-language-python

```
from azure.cognitiveservices.search.imagesearch import ImageSearchClient 
from msrest.authentication import CognitiveServicesCredentials

# This is my key generated by azure portal
subscription_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
# This is my endpoint generated by azure portal
subscription_endpoint = "https://vadmeggy-image-search.cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0"
search_term = "bird"

client = ImageSearchClient(endpoint=subscription_endpoint, credentials=CognitiveServicesCredentials(subscription_key))
image_results = client.images.search(query=search_term)
```

Exception:

`azure.cognitiveservices.search.imagesearch.models._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Resource Not Found'`

What am i missing? I called the REST API and that worked well with the given subscription key.
I can fallback to the REST API if the SDK doesn't work, but maybe somebody can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python implementation adds automatically the Bing version, you need to use

```
subscription_endpoint = "https://vadmeggy-image-search.cognitiveservices.azure.com"
```

and all will be well. It seems the documentation and implementation are out of sync.

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on the same issue for hours and this fixed it!